# Specific CSS line (NOT file) depending by web page visitor's browser

Tags: css, firefox, browser, compatibility

I have a **HTML** styled by a **CSS** file.
The problem is that I have several browser compatibility issues. To solve all my problems I need to add new **CSS** rules (margin or height) to fix my problem. I will need to change 5-6 divs, depending by the Web Page visitor's browser. 
For example let's take a specific `<div>` who is named: `#main_menu`

```
#main_menu{
widht: 800px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
}
```

Now, I need to add new CSS specific rules depending by Web Browser:

- For **Mozilla Firefox** I need to set: `height: 34;` instead of `height: 35;`
- For **Opera** I need to set: `top-margin: -3px;`
- For **Internet Explorer** I need to set: `top-margin: -2px;`

I've tried to do something like this, but unfortunately I don't know how it works:

```
#main_menu{
widht: 800px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;

-moz-height: 34; /* for Firefox */
-o-top-margin: -3px; /* for Opera */
-ms-top-margin: -2px; /* for IE */
}
```

P.S.: The **CSS** code works OK in Chrome and Safari.
Thank you for time!

Comment: Clean up your markup and clean up your CSS. Such inconsistencies come mostly from faulty markup.

Comment: Is well knowed that each browser interprets CSS differently. I tried to clean up and my problems stil exists.

Comment: Nowadays modern browsers pretty much comply when it comes to basic stuff like boxmodel and positioning. What messes it up are mostly errors in the markup like non-closed tags and so on... Show your markup (show your code and give a link to a testpage or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) and I'm sure we find a solution. And finally try to get rid of the illusion you can create pixelperfect layouts for all browsers.

Comment: Vendor prefixes aren't for feeding specific styles to a specific browser.  They're for experimental properties (or values) and once the spec has stabilized, they're supposed to go away in favor of a non-prefixed version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#selector{ /* Chrome or Safari */
    background: green;
}

#selector{ /* Internet Explorer 8 or bigger vers. */
    background: pink\9;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix(){ /* Firefox */
#selector{
background: lime;
}
}

doesnotexist:-o-prefocus, #selector{ /* Opera */
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="selector" style="padding:100px;">ss</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**What you're asking can't be done with CSS.**

The level of granularity provided by the CSS spec is to optionally include specific files (which you already know about). Combined with some degree of browser detection, you can deliver styles which override those present in your "base" styles.

It is quite common to use Internet Explorer's conditional comments for this purpose:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Vendor-specific prefixes (-ms, -moz, -webkit, etc.) aren't for targeting specific browsers. They're proprietory styles provided by the vendor to give some functionality which is not present in a formalised CSS specification. Often they will be "experimental" properties based on the in-development CSS specification, intended to be deprecated as the specification is formalised.

Answer (score 0):

There are no best practice ways to target specific browsers via CSS alone.  Vendor prefixes such as `-moz`, as mentioned in the comments, are for experimental or in-development specifications, and are removed from each browser when the feature is either deleted or "released".

If you absolutely must do browser targeting, try using JavaScript to detect the browser, and add a class which identifies to the body tag.  You can then write rules like the following:

```
body.firefox #main-menu { height: 34; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, just use this JS library and you can easily apply styles for every browser/os combination:

[BrowserClass.js](http://browserclass.org/)

With this you will get a class name on the body tag with the current name and version of the browser also with the used OS.

**In your case:**

After include the file:

```
<script src="js/browserclass.js"></script>
```

Sitewide settings, Your original one:

```
#main_menu{
  widht: 800px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

Firefox specific setting:

```
body.ff #main_menu{
    height: 34px
}
```

Opera specific setting:

```
body.opera #main_menu{
    top-margin: -3px;
}
```

Internet Explorer:

```
body.ie #main_menu{
    top-margin: -2px;
}
```

Note:
I would recommend to check IE by versions to make sure you get the same end result
[if IE] statmenets deprected since IE10 so this is the solution for that